# UIWebView and client certificates on iOS 6

Tags: ios, ssl, uiwebview

I'm trying to browse a secure web site (using a client certificate) via an UIWebView.
I'm using this example: [Client certificate authentication in UIWebView iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483472/client-certificate-authentication-in-uiwebview-ios/13062999#13062999)

It doesn't seems to work on iOS 6. I managed to handle the server trust but the client certificate seems to be ignored by the UIWebView. Even if I managed to connect to the server with ASIHTTPRequest and the identity.

The following error raised in the UIWebViewDelegate:

```
webView didFailLoadWithError :-1206 The server “xxx.yyy” requires a client certificate.`
```

I use the flag `NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession` for the `NSURLCredential`.

Comment: Any progress on this? I'm also stuck with this issue...

Comment: Can you post your -(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest: ?

Comment: Does the issue resolve now? Did you link up your UIWebView's delegate with the View Controller ?

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided contains correct solution to the problem. Just make sure you add the client certificate to the app bundle (Build Phases->Copy Bundle Resources in Xcode)